# Is there any way to quickly mock all methods of @SpyBean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, mockito

I have class

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserService {

    public void increaseBalance() {
      //increase balance
    }

    public void reduceBalance() {
     //reduce balance
    }
   
    //...other 10 methods
}
```

And in my test class I want to mock all UserService methods quickly.
Currently, I know that it can be done via doNothing()

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest()
public class UserServiceTest {
  @SpyBean
  private UserService userService;

  @Test
  public void testIncreaseBalance() {
    doNothing().when(userService).increaseBalance();
    doNothing().when(userService).reduceBalance();
    //...mock other 10 methods
  }

}
```

But I want to unify this process for different classes.
Ideally to have method like

```
mockAllMethods(userService);
```

Is there any way to do what I want?

Comment: What's the point of the spy then, if you want it to do nothing? A spy is used when you need the "original" dependency/object but want to mock away only a part of its behaviour. Also you don't need to mock everything in every test, only the parts that are used in the feature you're going to test.

Comment: Use mock bean instead perhaps? If you do not specify anything for a mock method it will, well 'do nothing'. Be careful tho, if its a method with a return type, you will get `null` as the response and you can get a NPE in code